# Get content from HTTP request even if there is no contentlength header

Tags: java, http, header

Am testing with a client who send me a HTTP request with no content length header but has a content.

How do I extract this content without the help of contentlength header?

Comment: Does the request include a `Transfer-Encoding:` header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've kept the original answer for completeness, but I've just been looking in the [HTTP RFC (2616)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4) section 4.3:

> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the request's message-headers. A message-body MUST NOT be included in a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1) does not allow sending an entity-body in requests. A server SHOULD read and forward a message-body on any request; if the request method does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request.

So if you haven't got a content length, you *must* have a Transfer-Encoding (and if you haven't, you should respond with a 400 status to indicate a bad request or 411 ("length required")). At that point, you do what the Transfer-Encoding tells you :)

Now if you're dealing with a servlet API (or a similar HTTP API) it may well handle all this for you - at which point you *may* be able to use the techique below to read from the stream until it yields no more data, as the API will take care of it (i.e. it won't just be a raw socket stream).

If you could give us more information about your context, that would help.

---

**Original answer**

If there's no content length, that means the content continues until the end of the data (when the socket closes).

Keep reading from the input stream (e.g. writing it to a ByteArrayOutputStream to store it, or possibly a file) until `InputStream.read` returns -1. For example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
// Now use the data in "output"
```

EDIT: As has been pointed out in comments, the client could be using a chunked encoding. Normally the HTTP API you're using should deal with this for you, but if you're dealing with a raw socket you'd have to handle it yourself.

The point about this being a request (and therefore the client not being able to close the connection) is an interesting one - I *thought* the client could just shut down the sending part, but I don't see how that maps to anything in TCP at the moment. My low-level networking knowledge isn't what it might be.

If this answer turns out to be "definitely useless" I'll delete it...

Comment: And the read should start after the end of the headers, right?

Comment: @Geo: Yes. Typically HTTP APIs parse the headers for you, and give you an input stream for the content.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was assuming that since he needs to do it this way, he can't rely on any existing classes.

Comment: This is certainly true for a response, but the OP said this was a **request**; how's the client supposed to read your response if it closed the connection?

Comment: If there's no content length, it can also mean that chunked encoding is in place. (I guess the proper answer depends on what layer is being used; it it's for instance a ServletInputStream then the servlet container will haven take care of that, and chunked encoding should already be dealt with)

Comment: @SimonJ If client needs response, why should the client close the connection? When a chunked stream has been fully sent, you only need to close the OutputStream on client side and keep the InputStream opened for server response.

Comment: @Julian: Yes, it could be chunked encoding, and as you say the servlet container would handle that.

Comment: @gigadot: IIRC closing a SocketOutputStream closes the underlying socket too. I suppose you could call Socket.shutdownOutput(), but I expect most webservers will just assume the client went away.

Comment: @SimonJ the question is about how to read the content sent from client. i don't think we should worry whether client closes the connection after he sends the content or not.

Comment: @gigadot: No, it's an entirely reasonable concern - because for a request, it doesn't make *sense* to close the whole connection before the server can reasonably respond. See my answer's edit.

Comment: @Jon: I suspect the client *could* just shut down the sending part, but I'm not sure many servers would bother responding in that case (distinguishing a half-close from a full close is trickier), hence a "real" client is unlikely to do it. The RFC discourages this approach for delimiting request bodies, too (section 4.4, item 5).

Comment: @SimonJ: If the client hasn't sent Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding, the server should probably respond with a 400 anyway :)

Comment: True - or even "411 Length Required". It's as if someone anticipated this scenario ;)

Comment: @SimonJ: Ooh, thanks - I hadn't spotted 411. Edited. There should be a 911 response code for "fire engine required".

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I guess 400 status or 411 as mentioned above is the correct behaviour .
My server recevies a POST HTTP request without a content lenght header and with a content body .Closing the connection wont help since I ve to give back a response .Also in HTTP rfc i saw content-lenght header is manadatory for packets with content body .So I think client needs to change its request :)

Comment: @Kozlov: Well, *either* Content-Length *or* Transfer-Encoding. Has the request got *neither*? If so, reject it.

Answer (score 3):

*If this were a response* then the message could be terminated by closing the connection. But that's not an option here because the client still needs to read the response.

Apart from `Content-Length:`, the other methods of determining content length are:

- `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`
- guesswork

Hopefully it's the former, in which case the request should look something like this:

```
POST /some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

25
This is the data in the first chunk

1C
and this is the second one

3
con
8
sequence
0
```

(shamelessly stolen from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and modified for a request)

- each chunk is of the form: hex-encoded length, CRLF, data, CRLF
- after the final data-carrying chunk comes a zero-length chunk with no data
- after the zero-length chunk comes optional extra HTTP headers
- after the optional HTTP headers comes another CRLF

Answer (score 0):

See [HTTPbis Part1, Section 3.3](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-12.html#rfc.section.3.3).